# Angular 1.x template-best practice to use CSS styles

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm a web developer, not an CSS expert. We recently started using Angular and I'm wondering what is the best practice applying styles in Angular templates.
Discussion we have at work is whether to use external CSS files or internal style tags. We do not have too many templates and each template mostly has its own unique styles. We are debating between external CSS files and/or internal styles.
Couls someone provide an expert opinion on this subject.

Comment: Use files. Can have lots of them and use build process to consolidate and minify them into one file.

Answer (score 0):

Internal styles are only applicable to the page that includes them. As such, if you want to update common styling (such as a menu) on multiple pages, you'll need to update **each page** individually.

Considering you'll almost definitely have certain styles apply to elements on more common to more than than one page, you'll *definitely* want to opt for external stylesheets. This allows pages A and B to both inherit styles from a single `style.css` or similar file.

This way, you can load all the relevant styles with a single line of code in the `<head>` of each page:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And you only have to update `style.css` when you want to update multiple page's styling.

Comment: Well, as I said most of these styles are going to be unique to their templates. But, surely, generic ones will be going into the global css file. Our discussion was more about whether we supposed to use internal css at all. I am personally not sure that styles that are only used in one template should be going into the global css.

Comment: I would still recommend only using a single CSS file. For a case such as this, I would recommend keeping views, controllers, and their associated styles in a single isolated folder. I would use a compiler to compile each of the various different CSS files back into your one global CSS file. This way, CSS files are easily 'separated' out in code structure.

Answer (score 0):

Angular brings scoped CSS from v1.5 up (when components were introduced - I believe). It's a good concept but, in small to medium apps, the difference is hardly noticeable. You should only consider using scoped CSS in conjunction with a tool that knows how to make the best of it (i.e. Webpack).

If you're not using Webpack, just stick to the classic model: one big style-sheet.

---

Note that technically, regardless of stack, if you want to provide the best possible experience (fastest loading times without FOUC) you want to put all the above-the-fold and general layout-ing styles inline, preferably in a head `<style>` tag and everything else inside a stylesheet loaded asynchronously.

Read [this article](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/async-css-without-javascript) about loading CSS async.